# Are there pointers in java? if not why do we get Nullpointer exception?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, null, nullreferenceexception

If there aren't pointers exposed to implement in java does Nullpointer exception need to be changed to Nullreference exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no pointers concept in Java unlike C/C++. You will get NPE when you are trying to perform some operation on a reference that is not pointing to any concrete object(is null). So you have references and it has a type  which points to an Object of that type or it's subclass.